# Analyzing Big Data using C# without OutOfMemory thrown

Tags: c#, excel, bigdata

I have `OutOfMemory` thrown always when I tried to analyze selective columns in my big data.

My big data stored in individual Excel files. Each file has more than 22 columns and more than 222330 records.

I need to read a selective columns then do statistical analysis. I read these selective columns into `Datatable` then `for loop` to study the contents.

As the code below:

```
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter_sido_Class4 = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select [Kvalitetsklass (null)],[Sido kortvåg vänster (null)], [Sido mellanvåg vänster (null)], [Sido långvåg vänster (null)]," + "[Sido kortvåg höger (null)], [Sido mellanvåg höger (null)], [Sido långvåg höger (null)]" + " from [Sheet1$]" + " where ([Kvalitetsklass (null)] = 4)", connection);

        DataTable dt_sido_Class4 = new DataTable();

        adapter_sido_Class4.Fill(dt_sido_Class4);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt_sido_Class4.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dt_sido_Class4.Rows[i].Field<double>(1) == 0)
            {
                sido_count10v++;

            }
            else if (dt_sido_Class4.Rows[i].Field<double>(4) == 0)
            {
                sido_count10h++;

            }
            else if (dt_sido_Class4.Rows[i].Field<double>(1) == null)
            {
                sido_count11v++;

            }
        }
```

I used `Where` condition to work on bunch of data instead of hole data.

In the same code, I tried to add more select of other columns and do other analysis, but I always got `OutOfMemory` exception. While, I used `Dispose()` and `Close()` to leave a space in memory for other calculations.

What suggestions do you have to process this big data?

Thank you,

Comment: It is not clear where the error occurs in your code. What happens when you run debug? What was the DataTable size then?

Comment: Thank you @EmmadKareem, do you mean load 61 Excel files with huge contents into database?, then use SQL for accessing and processing. Do you think this will be efficient?

Comment: Yes. This is what the ETL/Data Mart technology is about. Loading data into a table that does not have indexes is extremely fast. You could load millions of rows in few seconds. Of course in-memory DataTable would be faster - I don't argue with this but the standard ETL practice is to load data to database from source and perform analysis on the database data. You could also run many of the load processes in parallel.

Comment: This link may help:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41e1b19a-b5ee-4cf2-ac1e-ff0c9a35b961/out-of-memory-exception-adonet-dataset?forum=adodotnetdataset

Comment: Thanks @EmmadKareem. I am wondering if you have some resources to start with. Also, I did `OutOfMemory` exception but it is still useless with my data.

Comment: I have used commercial software in the past to do this but today you can do a lot with Open Source ETL tools or even C#. Without opting for a complex solution or a learning curve, you can do this in C#. Divide your project to Load job, Validate Job (optional), Insert Job and finally Analyze job. Control the sequence using a master controller program that controls the sequence of jobs and takes care of the files if needed.

Comment: In the past I used a cvs format which allowed only a selection of rows to be selected as data - reducing the memory load, would this approach be possible with columns? A quick search gave the following link: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/how-can-i-work-with-a-4gb-csv-file

Comment: @EmmadKareem could you explain more in details?. You mentioned to the process using C#. What kind of process should I follow in each step (Divide your project to Load job, Validate Job (optional), Insert Job and finally Analyze job.)?

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike, I used in the code above a way for selecting part of columns but memory problem always.

Comment: I would like to elaborate but the discussion is rather long and the space here would not permit. I think the step names are self explanatory. For example the extract job may read the Excel files convert them to CSV if necessary, the load job may run a bulk loader utility of the database of your choice, and so on.